# Cannot merge videos with express using ffmpeg: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'readable' in undefined

Tags: node.js, express, fluent-ffmpeg

The goal is to save video files into **api/videos/result** and then merge all videos in that folder into one video.

The npm module **fluent-ffmpeg** is throwing the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'readable' in undefined
    at FfmpegCommand.proto.mergeAdd.proto.addInput.proto.input (C:\Users\vmadmin\Desktop\M152-Frontend\node_modules\fluent-ffmpeg\lib\options\inputs.js:33:24)
    at C:\Users\vmadmin\Desktop\M152-Frontend\server.js:36:35
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\vmadmin\Desktop\M152-Frontend\server.js:30:12
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\vmadmin\Desktop\M152-Frontend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\vmadmin\Desktop\M152-Frontend\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\vmadmin\Desktop\M152-Frontend\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:53:37)
    at listener (C:\Users\vmadmin\Desktop\M152-Frontend\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:169:15)
    at onFinish (C:\Users\vmadmin\Desktop\M152-Frontend\node_modules\on-finished\index.js:100:5)
    at callback (C:\Users\vmadmin\Desktop\M152-Frontend\node_modules\ee-first\index.js:55:10)
```

I am not sure what to do with this error. I do neither have 'in' nor 'readable' somewhere in my code, so there wasn't anything specific for me to try.

```js
var mergedVideo = ffmpeg();
var upload = multer({storage: storage});
var single = upload.single('MyVideo');
var fs = require('fs');

});
// POST Request. Video is being uploaded here
app.post('/api/videos', single, function (req, res) {
    // Declares variable, that saves an array from all elements in result folder
    var source = fs.readdirSync('./api/videos/result/');
    // Loop, which iterates through each element in result folder
    source.forEach(function (element) {
        // Merge 'api', 'videos' and 'result' to one path
        var pathJoin = path.join('api', 'videos', 'result');
        // Save complete path with file in one variable
        var finalPath = console.log(__dirname + '\\' + pathJoin + '\\' + element);
        // Adds each file into the input for merging
        mergedVideo = mergedVideo.addInput(finalPath);
    });
    // Merge files and save them as merged.mp4
    mergedVideo.mergeToFile('./api/videos/merged.mp4', '/api/videos/tempDir/')
        .on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Error ' + err.message);
    })
        .on('end', function () {
        console.log('Finished!');
    });
    res.send(console.log('Hallo!'));
});
```

Expected a file named **merged.mp4** in the **api/videos** folder.

Answer (score 1):

I found the error in the code. The problem here is, that

`var finalPath = console.log(__dirname + '\\' + pathJoin + '\\' + element);`

returns void. (Because it's just a console output). Actually it should be

`var finalPath = __dirname + '\\' + pathJoin + '\\' + element;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it as mentioned below

```
var fs = require('fs');
var source = fs.readdirSync('./api/videos/result/');
```

I hope it would help you in this matter.

Comment: Actually, fs was already required, but I forgot to put it in. Fixed this now. Also I found the soluton in the meantime.